# What do the cards in table tennis mean?

Tags: rules, table-tennis, olympics

I saw in an Olympics table tennis match a Chinese athlete being given a red card. I think she lost the point but I'm not too sure.

So why would would some receive a red/yellow card in table tennis and what are the consequences of receiving one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Yellow and red cards were first introduced into the game of table tennis in 1991.
>   [image: Yellow & Red cards]
>   Yellow and red cards are shown by umpires and referees to players and coaches who break the rules or misbehave during the course of a match or tournament.
>
> Rule 3.05 covers the area of discipline in table tennis, and it applies to both players and coaches.
>
> The first part of this table tennis rule deals with coaches giving advice to players, Advice is only allowed to be given by a coach during the intervals between games or during other authorised suspensions of play.
>
> So if advice is given at any other time, the umpire will hold up a yellow card and warn the coach that any further offence will result in his dismissal from the playing area.
>   If the coach again gives advice illegally during the same match, the umpire will hold up a red card and send the coach away from the playing area.
>
> If this happens during a team match, and ANY authorised person gives advice to the player after a yellow card has been shown, the umpire will hold up a red card and send him away from the playing area, whether or not he was the person previously warned.
>   In a team match, the dismissed adviser is not allowed to return, except where he is required to play, and cannot be replaced by another adviser until the team match has ended.
>
> The second part of this table tennis rule deals with misbehaviour by players and coaches.
>
> The rules state that players and coaches must refrain from behaviour which may unfairly affect an opponent, offend spectators or bring the sport into disrepute.
>   Examples of this are - abusive language, deliberately breaking the ball or hitting it out of the playing area, kicking the table or surrounds and disrespect of match officials.
>
> Yellow cards are designed for less serious offences but if a player or coach commits a serious offence, the umpire must suspend play and report it immediately to the referee.
>   However, for less serious offences the umpire may, on the first occasion, hold up a yellow card and warn the offender that any further offence is liable to incur penalties.
>
> If the player then commits a second offence in the same individual match or team match, the umpire will award 1 point to the offender's opponent. And for a third offence he will award 2 points, each time holding up a yellow and a red card together.
>
> If a player continues to misbehave after three offences in the same individual match or team match, the umpire will suspend play and report it immediately to the referee.
>   If the coach continues to misbehave after receiving a yellow card, the umpire will hold up a red card and send the coach away from the playing area.

[Source](http://www.allabouttabletennis.com/yellow-cards.html)